# SFML not polling events in another thread

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

Well, i try fix bug but not can't

```cpp
while(window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    wm.lock();
    window.setActive(true);
    std::cout << "LOOP\n";
    while(window.pollEvent(event))
    {
       if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) 
       {
            window.close();
            return;
       }
        // ... more instructions
    }
    window.setActive(false);
    wm.unlock();
}
```

wm - is window mutex.

Then, i see in terminal:

```
**information of start rendering**
**mutex unlock**
LOOP
```

And stop. None. Very more lines "LOOP", and window SFML says on Windows system(don't try on linux) "does not answer".

setActive(false) in another thread has been called.
<window>.waitEvent(sf::Event&) also does not work.

I search on google, how to fix it, but not found answer.

Comment: SFML has specific recommendations about managing windows and events using threads. TL,DR: you should create windows and manage events on the main thread only for portability

Comment: TL/DR?
Idk, but I see on docs about window.waitEvent - use on thread for events.
I want use other thread because SFML make pause on always events.

Example:
press a;
...pause...;
press a;
press a;
I think, you understand me.

Comment: Was the the window created in the same thread that's polling events? And from the [SFML documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php): "If you really want to split things between threads, it is more convenient to keep event handling in the main thread and move the rest (rendering, physics, logic, ...) to a separate thread instead."

Comment: Also, you're currently leaking the mutex when you receive a `Closed` event. You should use [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) instead of manually calling `lock()/unlock()`

Comment: Yeah. It's look that due to refactor, 
I try it. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `setActive` if you're not doing any OpenGL rendering?

Comment: Rendering him, just replace her on '...instructions'.
Him work on main thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean